# QML ComboBox works only one time

Tags: combobox, model, qml

With QT 5.10 my ComboBox is selectable only once. After the first select it remains closed and no further selection is possible. Is this the standard behaviour or a bug? How can I "unlock" the ComboBox again?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ComboBox {
        width: 100
        model: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    }
}
```

After program start:
[image]

Selecting:
[image]

Locked:
[image]

Comment: What is your OS? In Windows 10 that works without any problem. It looks that you didn't provide the complete code.

Comment: In Linux it also works correctly.

Comment: Windows 7 or Windows 10; same behaviour.The code is the complete qml. The rest is a Qt Creator default project; nothing else.